# Javascript most efficient way to build objects from 2 tabs linked by Id

Tags: javascript, arrays, list, object

I receive from an API a json with 2 lists.

In the first list there are objects with theses attributes : id, name, type, label.

For the objects of the 2nd list, the attributes are: id, name, order.
The id of the 2nd list refer to the id of the first list, there can be several objects that refer to a single one of the 1st list (many to one) but it is also possible that there is not (zero to one).

I would like to create one object with these attributes: id, name, type, label, tab. Where tab would have all the objects from the second list that refer to the 1st list.

What would be the most efficient way to do this ?

Sample of arrays:

1st array:

```
{id : 1, name: 'colors', type: 'list', label:'xxx'},
{id : 2, name: 'yyy', type: 'date', label:'yyy'},
{id : 3, name: 'dogs', type: 'list', label:'zzz'}
```

2nd array:

```
{id:1, name:'blue', order:1},
{id:1, name:'red', order:2},
{id:1, name:'green', order:3},
{id:3, name:'husky', order:1},
{id:3, name:'bulldog', order:2},
{id:3, name:'dalmatian', order:3}
```

Wanted result:

```
{id : 1, name: 'colors', type: 'list', label:'xxx', options: [
    {id: 1, name:'blue', order:1},
    {id: 1, name:'red', order:2},
    {id: 1, name:'green', order:3}]},
{id : 2, name: 'yyy', type: 'date', label:'yyy', tab: []},
{id : 3, name: 'dogs', type: 'list', label:'zzz', options: [
    {id: 3, name:'husky', order:1},
    {id: 3, name:'bulldog', order:2},
    {id: 3, name:'dalmatian', order:3}
]}
```

Comment: Please add a sample of the 2 arrays

Comment: First of all when you are thinking about the most efficient way to do this, it is the best to get the consolidated data from the API itself. That way you would reduce the network time for two different rest calls.

Comment: it depends on the size if second list is small you can convert it into object map indexed with id and then run map on the first list requesting objects from that object map by id.
If second its large you can do some memoized function for retriving data from it. If you can do it on server side it would be better...

Comment: @adiga i added the samples.

Comment: @SaiKarthik i can't change the API, i would like i can.

Comment: @Xesenix the 2nd can be large or small, it depends on the request but it never more larger than 1000 objects i think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
var m = {};
var arr1 = [{id : 1, name: 'colors', type: 'list', label:'xxx'},
            {id : 2, name: 'yyy', type: 'date', label:'yyy'},
            {id : 3, name: 'dogs', type: 'list', label:'zzz'}];
var arr2 = [{id:1, name:'blue', order:1},
            {id:1, name:'red', order:2},
            {id:1, name:'green', order:3},
            {id:3, name:'husky', order:1},
            {id:3, name:'bulldog', order:2},
            {id:3, name:'dalmatian', order:3}];
for(var i=0;i<arr1.length;i++){
    arr1[i]["options"] = [];
    m[arr1[i]["id"]] = arr1[i];
}
for(var i=0;i<arr2.length;i++){
    if(m.hasOwnProperty(arr2[i]["id"])){
        m[arr2[i]["id"]]["options"].push(arr2[i]);
    }
}
console.log(arr1);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let person = [
    {id : 1, name: 'colors', type: 'list', label:'xxx'},
    {id : 2, name: 'yyy', type: 'date', label:'yyy'},
    {id : 3, name: 'dogs', type: 'list', label:'zzz'}
];

let hobby = [
    {id:1, name:'blue', order:1},
    {id:1, name:'red', order:2},
    {id:1, name:'green', order:3},
    {id:3, name:'husky', order:1},
    {id:3, name:'bulldog', order:2},
    {id:3, name:'dalmatian', order:3}
];

let arr = person.map((item, i) => Object.assign({}, item, hobby[i]));

console.log(arr);
```

Comment: i edited my question so you can see what i expect as output. I think the solution you gave will only merge the both.